# Adaptive Multi Rate (AMR) decoder

Tags: codecs

I need to play .amr files (adaptive multi-rate)
When I click on one I get this sequence:

> Unable to play file
>   Adaptive Multi Rate (AMR) decoder is required to
>   play the file, but is not installed
>   Find in Ubuntu Software
>   Unable to find requested software

I see a feature request from years ago:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/+bug/93849

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you tried to install ffmpeg? `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, also I recommend you mpv and vlc as a video players: `sudo apt-get install vlc mpv` - choose one that fits you most

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have ffmpeg and vlc, but not mpv. I installed using the command you show. Clicking on the amr file results in the same messages. Is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: @AlLelopath Have you tried by using the: 'File --> Open' function of vlc?

Comment: That works. You can make that the answer if you so desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can certainly reproduce this issue on a stock installation of Ubuntu 18.04 where the *default* media player chokes on amr files:

[image]

There  are a variety of ways to fix this issue but in my opinion you are best to install vlc from the Ubuntu Repository. Open a Terminal window and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

This will play amr / 3gp files with no issues from the `File --> Open` command but if you wish to open these files from a double click a little more work will be required.

Navigate to your amr file and:

1. Right click on the file and select 'Properties'
2. Select 'Open With...'
3. Scroll down to 'vlc' and select it
4. Click on 'Set as default...'

And then you should be able to double click on your amr file and have it play in vlc. Below is screenshot illustrating the final steps mentioned above:

[image]

And now you can play your amr files directly in vlc with a simple double click!

**References:**

- A sample amr file for experimentation can be found [here...](https://samples.mplayerhq.hu/A-codecs/amr/sample.amr)